# Is this .NET Framework bug with Me.Top?

Tags: c#, vb.net, .net-4.0, screen-resolution

I think I have found a bug when setting or getting the Me.Top property of a form. 
I am using VS2010 VB.NET .NET framework 4.0

My monitor setup is slightly unusual:

1. Primary 1600 x 900
2. 1680 x 1050
3. 1680 x 1050

[image]

On monitor number 1 everything works as expected. On monitor 2 or 3 if I set `Me.Top = 0` then the form appears 150 pixels from the top of the screen so it thinks that it is using the resolution of the primary monitor.

I have to set `Me.Top = -150` to get the form to the top of the screen.

Has anyone seen this before / know of a fix or workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a bug. The coordinate system is related to the primary screen.
In your layout of screens the screens 2 and 3 has their top bound "higher" than the screen 1 (the primary screen).

If you want layout your window to the top bound of the screen, you should use the [Screen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.aspx) class.

Comment: So I have to manually work out if the screens are bottom or top aligned to work out if I need to adjust my value?

Comment: It looks like you can just use `Screen.FromControl(Me).WorkingArea.Top`